# php error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

I am adapting a script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940454/php-detect-get-the-sender-url-or-server-of-post-request), to use as verification when form is posted.

This is the code being sent form the form page:

```
<?php
$secret1 = '00001';
?>
```

And the code from the action page:

```
if(!empty(htmlentities($_POST['secret1'])) {
    if(htmlentities($_POST['secret1']) == '00001') {
        echo 'PASS';
    }
}else { echo 'ERROR'; }
```

However, when I submit the form, I get "Can't use function return value in write context" error.

Am just starting to learn php so can't really identify the problem. Can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Count your opening and closing parenthesis in that first `if(){}` block

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Tried adding another parenthesis (!empty(htmlentities($_POST['secret1']))), same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173318/2191572

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Remove the exclamation point? I'm a newb .

Comment: Where do you actually POST the `$secret1` value? It's not going to exist in the `$_POST` array just because you defined it in some PHP code...

Comment: `$secret1 = '00001';` is on the page with the form. And the rest of the code is on the form action page. @Cory

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a function return (htmlentities) to empty. Change your first line to:

```
if(!empty($_POST['secret1'])) {
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What do you mean?

Comment: @Joey, Didn't really solve my problem. Get another error. I am trying to verify the sender of the form by using a code.

Comment: @JoeyHinton I think _@MonkeyZeus_ is referring to your parenthesis. Count your parenthesis. Open ***2***, close ***1***...

Comment: @JoeyHinton Doesn't work. I am supposed to get echo PASS, I get else

Comment: Regardless of any other errors, this IS the cause of the error in your question.

Comment: @Boris This fix solved your error. The problems you're having with the post variable are a separate issue. Just because you post a page, all the variables will not post. They have to be inside a form element. 

`<input type='hidden' name='secret1' value='00001' />`

in place of setting a variable on the form page would probably solve this issue. But I can't know for sure without seeing that page.

Comment: @JoeyHinton No, I am trying to send it to the next page via PHP. Using POST and REQUEST maybe?

Comment: @Boris Once again you are now stuck on a post issue. You should mark this as the correct answer for the question you posted and post a new question with the code on the page you are trying to post. 

You have moved past the error you posted here and arrived at a new problem where your data isn't posting.

Comment: @Boris: If you don't have a `<input type="hidden" name="secret1" value="<?=$secret1?>" />` inside a `<form ... method="POST">` on your page, then you will never have a value in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: @Cory Is it possible to use SESSIONS instead? What I am trying to achieve is have the form page have a unique code, that the second page will recognize and grant access. If not it will show else. Point is, it's not supposed to be publicly visible.

Comment: @Boris: I would research CSRF prevention methods. Perhaps start here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. You will find that cookies, session, POST, etc. are not safe for the simple methodology you have used here. You need something smarter.